# Word request - male who has affairs with many girls

Tags: word-request

Is there any English informal and a bit insulting term for a male who has many affairs with females and who always long for more females?

Comment: I don't know since when, but apparently, [Casanova](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/Casanova) is an English word!

Comment: Philanderer or libertine, although neither are "informal."

Comment: Having ***many*** affairs without being *sexually involved* is not possible. Or else, they are not *affairs!* :) So, my vote is for Philanderer (+1).

Comment: [related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202885/is-there-a-phrase-or-slang-word-for-a-man-who-is-always-chatting-women-up)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the word " [womaniser](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/womanize?q=womaniser#womanize__14)"

> (Of a man) engage in numerous casual sexual affairs with women (used
>   to express disapproval):

Comment: Could we say that "a lady killer" is the polite/positive equivalent of "a womanizer ?"

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Yes, that too.

Comment: When sex is not involved, only affairs and attempts towards females?

Comment: @Man_From_India "ladies' man"

Answer (score 1):

A "playboy" is a man who "plays the field".  In other words, he "has affairs with many women."  "Playboy" has both positive and negative connotations.  *Playboy* magazine is a literary magazine for men who like to look at nude pictures of beautiful women.  It was founded by Hugh Hefner, a famous playboy.

A contemporary meaning of "player" is a (wannabe-) man who tries to "score" with women by getting them to ignore "*The Rules*" of "the dating game".  This meaning of "player" has many negative connotations.  *The Rules* was a famous book of dating advice for women looking to get married.  The book *The Game* is a piece of autobiography / journalism that follows one "player" as he learns the "game", and then becomes disillusioned.

"Wannabe" is a derogatory word for someone who "wants to be" something that he is not yet (or may never be).  For example, a "wannabe gangster" aspires to be a member of a street gang.  ("Wannabe gangster" is often shortened to just "wannabe".)

All three of these words are informal American English.  "Playboy" is the least informal.  "Player" is very informal and easily confused with other meanings of "player", such as "athlete" or "poker player".  "Wannabe" is also very informal.